# ¿Por qué ejecuto un script simple y funciona, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo desde otro me da error?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Estoy intentando crear un script sencillo para practicar.

Quiero que escanee la red y los puertos por separado.

Tengo el script principal que se llama **`script-bash.sh`** y este mediante el paso de parámetros (**Ejemplo:** `./script-bash.sh -hd 192.168.1.0`) escanea la red que le digamos.

Tengo un script aparte que es el que se encarga de escanear la red, se llama **`ipScan.sh`**.

Lo que hago es mediante el comando `source` llamar al script y pasarle la dirección de red como parámetro, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
source ./scripts/ipScan.sh $parametro**.
```

La cosa es que cuando ejecuto el script **`ipScan.sh`** por separado funciona correctamente pero cuando lo llamo desde el script **`./script-bash.sh`** me da error.

¿Alguien sabe el por que?

Si me podéis echar una mano os lo agradecería.

Código:

[*] Llamo al script mediante la función *HostDiscovery*:

```
function host_discovery(){
    write_header '(UP)Host discovery'
    source ./scripts/ipScan.sh $parameter 2> /dev/null
}
```

[*] Script **`ipScan.sh`**:

```
network_ip=$1

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c(){
    echo -e "\n\n[*] Exiting ..."
    tput cnorm; exit 0
}

NETWORK=`echo $network_ip | sed -e 's/..$//'`

tput civis; for i in $(seq 1 255); do
        timeout 1 bash -c "ping -c 1 $NETWORK.$i" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo -e ">
done

tput cnorm;
```

Comment: He tenido situaciones similares con programas java y el error se presenta en las rutas relativas que se usan en el segundo script debido a que al ejecutar el primer script el ambiente de ejecución esta en relación a donde este ubicado y las rutas relativas que se usen en el segundo script se buscaran a partir de ese ambiente y no a partir de donde esta ubicado el segundo script.

Comment: Intenta llamar el script sin la palabra source, simplemente cambia por `./scripts/ipScan.sh $parameter 2> /dev/null`, y si sigue igual, comprueba los permisos del script, asegurate de que el usuario que ejecuta los 2 scripts sea el mismo o almenos tenga permiso sobre ambos, tambien puedes dejarnos el output del error que te da.

Comment: He probado a quitar el **source** y funciona gracias por la ayuda !!!!!!

Comment: Es difícil ayudar sin saber que error te da. Mira aquí por las diferencias entre ejecutar un script y llamarlo con `source` (en ingles): [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882). También fíjate que `source` es un "bashismo" y no funcionará con `sh` o `dash` u otros shells POSIX. La versión estándar y POSIX de `source` es simplemente `.`.